# How to append html to first occurance of string after selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have html like so:

```
<div class=foo>
  (<a href=forum.example.com>forum</a>)
  <p>
  Some html here....
</div>
```

And I want to insert another link after the first one, like so:

```
<div class=foo>
  (<a href=forum.example.com>forum</a>) <a href=blog.example.com>blog</a>
  <p>
  Some html here....
</div>
```

...but because it is enclosed in `()` I cannot use:

```
$('div.foo a:first').append(' <a href=blog.example.com>blog</a>');
```

...which would place it before the `)`.

So how can I extend my jQuery selection to select the literal `)` or do I need to use another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either match and replace the whole `(<a />)` string, or place another element (such as a span) around the whole thing.

```
<span>(<a href=forum.example.com>forum</a>)</span>
```

Append is also inserting the new anchor tag inside the existing anchor. You'll probably find you're looking for [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after)

Answer (score 1):

Could you possibly select the next `<p>` tag and prepend (actually...use the [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/) method) the link?

```
$('div.foo a:first').next('<p>').before(' <a href=blog.example.com>blog</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

One should never modify XML/HTML (especially untrusted/illformatted) by regular expressions, but if you are really desperate:

```
var container = $('div.foo');
var append = '<a href="...">...</a>';
var html = container.html();
var replaced = html.replace(/\(<a [^\)]+\)/, "$& " + append);
container.html(replaced);
```

Note that the above will fail if you have ")" character inside a-tag.